# Unix command 'mail', send mail to an .onion address mail

Tags: proxy, email

In my server, I installed tor and postfix. I can send an email via this simple shell commands :

```
echo "foo" | mail -s "example" testest@sigaint.org
```

No problem here, its work.

Now, I want be able to send emails to .onion address. So When I execute this command :

```
echo "foo" | mail -s "example" testest@sigaintdjfu3jveh.onion
```

The mail isn't received in my email address. Below my mail.log logs :

> Nov 29 00:50:10 mycomputername postfix/pickup[6641]: 49B4F342961:
>   uid=1001 from=myunixuser
>
> Nov 29 00:50:10 mycomputername postfix/cleanup[6974]: 49B4F342961:
>   message-id=<20161128235010.49B4F342961@mycomputername>
>
> Nov 29 00:50:10 mycomputername postfix/qmgr[6642]: 49B4F342961:
>   from=, size=297, nrcpt=1 (queue
>   active)
>
> Nov 29 00:50:10 mycomputername postfix/smtp[6976]: 49B4F342961:
>   to=, relay=none, delay=0.19,
>   delays=0.12/0.01/0.05/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain
>   name not found. Name service error for name=sigaintevyh2rzvw.onion
>   type=AAAA: **Host not found**)

I think I must configure my 'mail' command for use the proxy tor, but I don't know how I can do that and I didn't find any doc/tutorial..
Thank you =)

Comment: Tried `torsocks mail ...`?

Comment: Oh wait, you need to Torify your postfix daemon...probably want to use transparent proxying then.

Comment: I installed tor, so I can use the command torsocks. But I don't see how I must use this command for my issue.. I also installed postfix, if you know what commands/configurations I must use, it would be appreciated :)

Comment: I don't know if postfix supports using proxies natively, so you'd likely need to setup transparent proxying.

Comment: Also be aware that currently your postfix installation is telling your upstream DNS resolver that you're trying to contact sigaints onion.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your case consists of two parts, actually:

- **Sending mail** *from command line to the MTA* - Here you need to spool your message from a command line into the *thing* that will deliver it from this step forward. It can be either Postfix, or *any* other. I prefer QMail
- **Delivering mail to dot-onion addresses** - Here you need to handle *all* steps as in clearnet, but in Darknet. And a proxy is a **bad** solution!

So - how to do it? Let's take a look:

- *First* check [this manual](http://www.unix.com/man-page/netbsd/5/mailer.conf/) about `mailer.conf` and make sure that *everything* is pointed out correctly to your MTA. It usually looks like this:

  ```
  # $FreeBSD: head/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/mail/chapter.xml 48529 2016-04-03 18:57:15Z wblock $
  #
  # Execute the "real" sendmail program, named /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
  #
  sendmail        /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
  send-mail       /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
  mailq           /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
  newaliases      /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
  hoststat        /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
  purgestat       /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
  ```

Check that *every* line is pointing to your MTA corresponding tools, not just `sendmail` and `send-mail`! It's a common problem in "fast howto's"...

- *Second*, in your Tor installation, you don't need *any* proxy-stuff for mail processing - inbound and outbound. You will need two features of Tor to implement *proper* handling of the "email stuff": host mapping and DNS backend. In your `torrc` you should enable it like that:

  ```
  VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4 10.192.0.0/10
  AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
  DNSPort 53
  DNSListenAddress 127.0.0.2
  TransPort 9040
  TransListenAddress 127.0.0.1
  ```

  So all the dot-onion addresses will be mapped out to the desired network range. Pay attention: you should *not* interfere with your ISP local subnets(if there any) and a home/LAN ones! You should use the range big enough to map lots of hosts, so 10.0.0.0/8 subnet is a good choice for that.
- *Third*, you will need a **properly installed full DNS local server**, no "tiny-stubs" or "fast-but-truncated-in-functionality DNS systems". And here is why: mail processing involves lots of DNS-elaborating techniques, like RBL checking, hostname resolution e.t.c. Set up a full-featured BIND and point the dot-onion names to Tor listening on 127.0.0.2 like that:

  ```
  zone "onion" {
      type forward;
      forward only;
      forwarders {
          127.0.0.2;
      };
  ```

  In your MTA settings *explicitly disable* reverse DNS checks on incoming SMTP connections(for receiving inbound mail) and in SMTP use STARTTLS first, i.e. do not accept plaintext SMTP, it's a bit risky of spam. But you can use it if you wish - it's just a warning. SMTPS is the best way In My Humble Opinion =)
- *Fourth*, use a firewall to divert all the traffic to your Tor mapping zone (specified in `torrc` in `VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4 xxx` option) to your TransPort: because once resolved, the packets must go to the packet trap, *not via routing table*! In `iptables` it is done like this:

  ```
  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $_int_if -p tcp --syn -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_trans_port
  ```

All the variables are self-explaining, but `_int_if` is another loopback device with an address like 127.0.0.3 - bind *everything* for your MTA to use that address as a source address, binding address and the interface bind. The config depends on the MTA, so check your MTA doc's ;)

And that's it! Of course there're mane optional tweaks *can be done*, but they do depend on an MTA, the mailserver setup and the task specifics. All the steps above will give you the full power of darknet mail =) Feel free to ask questions if you have ones!

Comment: Houuuu thanks for this detailed answer ! Ill test by this weekend :)

Comment: it's a Mail Transfer Agent - a software component that "takes mail and delivering it". Examples are Postfix, Sendmail, QMail, Exim

Comment: I found that after some websearches :) but thanks indeed

Comment: one word of advice - try to use QMail instead of Postfix. It's a bit more difficult to configure, but it's a way more flexible in tweaking the tiny pieces.

Comment: I note your advise =) I think Ill choose according the amount of documentation (QMail or Postfix) Ill find on the web during my 'tor' sending email installation/configuration. I need increaze my knowledges about it and I know my server configuration won't work on my first try ;)

Comment: Don't be upset about "not from a first time"! Even after 26 years in IT my setups don't work from a first time in 100% cases, *and it's OK*! Try and learn - that's bloody and beery fun!

Comment: That `iptables` rule will divert all traffic, not just that intended for .onion and `-i` should be an interface name, not an address and at no point is it suggested that they will also need to point their OS resolvers to 127.0.0.1. It would make more sense to keep the default `VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4` range since its less likely to conflict, being on the localloopback interface.

Comment: Note aswell that the `DNSPort` does not support `MX` record lookups, only `A`, `AAAA` and `PTR` so the lack of `MX` records may break some MTAs (although in theory the `@` `A` record is meant to be the fallback in the case of no `MX` records some MTAs do not honour it)

Comment: the iptables will route all traffic *for a specific interface* - that's the point! No proxy-style problems will *ever* pop-up. And yes, DNSPort is pretty generic, so that's why you need full DNS local setup and why I recommend QMail - it's very tweakable MTA.