# How to send emails from my server with TOR?

Tags: email

I've a linux server with Postfix and I want to send emails from my server with TOR to clear email addresses like "gmail", "yahoo", etc.

How can I setup Postfix to send emails with TOR?

Can you explain me in details?
Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix command 'mail', send mail to an .onion address mail](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13246/unix-command-mail-send-mail-to-an-onion-address-mail)

Comment: NO, I want to send emails to CLEAR email addresses, NOT .onion address email.

Comment: You understand, of course, that this simply won't work because all Tor exit's which can exit to port 25 (which is very limited) are all on multiple blacklists? And you'd need to own a valid domain that specifies all of the Tor exit relays in it's SPF record, etc. This simply will not work even if you get it to "work", your mail will be rejected as spam on the basis that it's coming from Tor.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and good time of the day! To avoid too-overcomplicated setups just use a routing via firewall for all the MTA(Postfix in your case) usernames to route them directly through Tor. The only delicate spot here is the DNS - use your own local BIND setup to resolve all the stuff - Tor does **not** work with UDP, so it will fail to tunnel DNS requests via Tor too, and Tor's DNS backend is very limited in functionality, so it won't work for a mail server as it should(because Tor DNSPort is made for some different tasks).